# Getting semantic issue "property tabBarItem not found on object of type FeedViewController" on xcode 6, but on xcode 5.1.1 its working fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = @"Feed";
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_icon_feed"];// this line causing issue

}
return self;
 }
```

This is the method causing the problem.Not sure if you need some more code in order to see whats wrong if yes just let me now. I dont really understand what went wrong because it was working and suddenly this error appeared.

Comment: Did you create a new project in XCode6 and add this class or did you take a working Xcode 5.1.1 project and open it in Xcode 6?

Comment: it was working xcode 5.1.1 project and i opened it in xcode6

Comment: its defined in the Xib, i havent created it programatically

Comment: When you get something like tabBarItem not found it is sometimes that the import of UIKit has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try import UIKit:
`@import UIKit;`